# What is the best way to do 'Reset Password' functionality in php?

Tags: php

What is the best way to do 'Reset Password' functionality in php ?

Two step process.

- User will enter the email Id, mail will send him to user with the link.
- When user click the link, he can see tow fields to reset his password.

Can anybody right the script flow for this ?

Comment: Where are you stuck in implementing this? Sounds like you got the basic idea right.

Comment: Important thing is that the url should be for one-time usage only. And after request it should expire

Comment: I agree with @zerkms. Also reset url should need an expire date too.

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track. Are you having any specific issues with your code? If you're asking us to write the code for you ("can anybody right the script flow for this?"), then you should know that's really not the point of this site. We're here to answer questions, not do your work for you.

Comment: Just a prototype. Not full script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i hope this will help you. first you have to  create a table name "token" with  a column of seqid,tokenid,status.. sequence id will represent the sequence number tokenid in a hash form  and the status it explain itself.

Now you have to compute a url that is one time used only after the user click the reset password the system will generate a tokenid (its up to you how to  generate a hash value) 
and then compose a url that will be submitted to the user via email

domain name/function Or Page ? username(in hash form) & tokenid

example:

http://www.yourdomain.com/resetpassword.php?_u=82cc5b9e02d711035aafef9e18c7eb26973e8962&tokenid=82cc5b9e02d711035aafef9e18c7eb26973e8962

after the user click the url it will go to function and check who is the user or if it is existing and the tokenid if it is already expired

```
 ex. "select user from users where sha1(username) = $userInHashForm "
     "Select * from token where tokenid = $tokenid AND status = 'active'"
```

and then reset his/her password when its done you need  to change the status of the token to "inactive" so it cannot be used again

thanks please rate! goodluck